# How to use HTML progress bar with angular

Tags: html, angular, progress-bar

How to use HTML buil-in progress bar with Angular:

```
<label for="file">File progress:</label>

<progress id="file" max="100" value="70">30%</progress>
```

What I mean how to change dynamically `value` from angular component. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this in Angular, you could make use of "Data Binding".

In your Angular component TS file, create a variable to store the current progress:

```
 progressValue: number = 30;
```

Then just insert the value in, so that it is dynamic, as follows:

```
<label for="file">File progress:</label>
    <progress id="file" max="100" [value]="progressValue">{{ progressValue }}%</progress>
```

If you want to change the progress bar, then the variable will be altered in the TS file.

Reference: https://angular.io/guide/binding-syntax